# Firebase Custom Parameters Not Being Displayed

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I am sending Custom Parameters as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWyHZ.png)
i also created custom metrics as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ8LH.png)
but when i try to add comparisons it doesnt show up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMVrS.png)
although these custom dimensions show up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqD7u.png)
am i doing something wrong? ad is debug needed for firebase ? because i tried but unfortunately its not possible for unity also i checked there are no errors and the events are bein glogged properly

I tried and followed the steps given in the documentation not sure where am i going wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.